# How to use smtp as a third party library in codigniter

Tags: codeigniter, smtp

i am using codeingniter framework for my website. And i am trying to adding smtp as third party library. How could i add this?

Answer (score 0):

Please read full documentation here [Codigniter email configration](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)